Do I need an Airport transit visa for traveling through Greece?
I am an Armenian passport holder, Armenian citizen.
I want to travel from Armenia to Serbia via Athens airport. All flights via Aegean airlines. (Yerevan > Athens > Belgrade and vice versa Belgrade > Athens > Yerevan) I should stay in Athens airport few hours in international zone.
I don't need any visa to Serbia.
Should I have any visa for traveling through Greece? Airport Transit Visa or kinda?

It seems that Armenian citizens require airport transit visas in the Czech Republic and Poland, but the requirements change from time to time.  The linked duplicate explains how to find the current list.
